# How to change header Background of Tab in Expo Router?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I used Expo Router in Expo 50 and i don't know how to set header background color for each tab:

```
<Tabs.Screen
    name="two"
    options={{
      title: 'Tab Two',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="code" color={color} />,
      // i don't know which prop to set background color and its syntax.
    }}
  />
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you a lot

Comment: Here is your solution

          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerTitle:"Explore",headerTintColor:Colors.white,headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.dark}}}/>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using headerStyle :

```
<Tabs.Screen
name="two"
options={{
  title: 'Tab Two',
  tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="code" color={color} />,
  headerStyle: {
                 backgroundColor: //color you want,
               },
}}
/>
```